# What is cache profile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, cacheprofile

I encountered with it while I was reading [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute) from MSDN documentation. I am pretty newbie about caching, in fact, one of the first articles that I read about caching. Can you explain me simply?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short its a caching profile that you can set in the `web.config` instead of having to apply the settings to every Action or Controller you want to use the cache settings with:

In web.config you specify options for the cache profile:

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="cp1" duration="30" location="Any" varyByHeader="user-agent" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
  </system.web>
```

Then anywhere you want to use the profile you can just use e.g.

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile="cp1")]
public ActionResult Index() {
     //...
}
```

Above example taken from [Apress Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 Platform by Adam Freeman](http://www.apress.com/9781430265412).
I recommend it as a good read.

Comment: Thank you James, your answer is really clear. But I wonder how can I apply cache settings every action or controller. Maybe it's not needful information but I want to see an example. Thank you again.

Comment: I found this blog article(https://prashantbrall.wordpress.com/2013/09/29/using-output-cache-profile-in-asp-net-mvc/) maybe you can take a look, it was the answer to my second question. Thank you for your interest  again.